# How to identify cycles in Time series with pandas tools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, time-series

My problem is that i have dataframe as:

```
                          Time     Value  Invalid

0      2017-08-06 00:00:51.561  0.000000    False

1      2017-08-06 00:00:51.610  0.035937    False

2      2017-08-06 00:00:51.690  0.071875    False

3      2017-08-06 00:00:51.711  0.035020    False

4      2017-08-06 00:00:51.760  0.000000    False

...

9000000
```

I would like to count how many cycles there are in this data and identify each cycle with starting time and ending time. There should be many cycles and all start and end to zero value. How can I identify this with python/pandas?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try something to do that? If so, you can share even if it fails. Btw, welcome.

Comment: I could not find any help and that is why I tried asking here. Thank you btw.

Comment: Ok, I am still not clear about what is a 'cycle' in your case (I mean, are they the rows whose Value column is 0 etc.). Still, [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) functionality can be a fit for you.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/y9zjcmm7b/
This link has a plot of my data. So there are cycles which are irregular and I'd like to identify all cycles by start and ending time.

Comment: No on know this?